# How to build a 32 bits version of a Python 3RD PARTY LIBRARY on my Win10 64 bits PC for a target machine running a 32 bits interpreter?

Tags: python, pip

I need to package a Python library for someone using a Python 3.6.x 32 bits version so that he can pip install it. He can't change his Python interpreter so switching to 64 bits won't be possible to do.

Part of the library is written in C so compilation is needed because binaries for his Win32 3.6 interpreter version aren't available from the internet.

I'm on a Win10 64 bits machine. How can I compile and build a 32 bits version of the lib he could then install on his machine? Is there a pip command to do so? I Have MSVC build tools installed on my machine (2015-2022 x64 and x86).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the C code...

From here: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html

```
python setup.py build --plat-name=win-amd64
```

So I'd suggest trying

```
--plat-name=win32
```

Comment: Great. It looks the simple right solution :) I'll try and keep in touch